# PHP Deprecated: html_entity_decode(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string

Tags: deprecation

Since the change to PHP 8.1 (from 8, WP 6.3 is now running, I get once a day, only while opening the dashboard this warnings (repeating twice):

```
"PHP Deprecated:  html_entity_decode(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /homepages/xxx/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 1626"
```

Only once day I'm logged in. After reloading or new login on the same day, the warning doesn't show up.
This happens on three different Installations.
On one Installation I deactivated all Plugins and changed the theme to a fresh Twenty Twenty Two.

But still once a day the warning show up just after first login.

The Cron-Jobs running, are only from WP, see below.

Searched Google about this warning, I got no result about this warning in releation with "html_entity_decode()" & "wp-includes/widgets.php on line 1626"

So, I'm not sure this is a known bug in WP Core onto PHP 8.1

Any suggestion would be welcome.
thanx

the Cron-Jobs running:

> "wp_privacy_delete_old_export_files,wp_privacy_delete_old_export_files(),""once
> every hour""
> "recovery_mode_clean_expired_keys,WP_Recovery_Mode->clean_expired_keys(),""once a day"" "wp_https_detection,wp_update_https_detection_errors(),""twice
> a day"" "wp_version_check,wp_version_check(),""twice a day""
> "wp_update_plugins,wp_update_plugins(),""twice a day""
> "wp_update_themes,wp_update_themes(),""twice a day""
> "wp_scheduled_delete,wp_scheduled_delete(),""once a day""
> "delete_expired_transients,delete_expired_transients(),""once a day""
> "wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete,wp_delete_auto_drafts(),""once a day""
> "wp_update_user_counts,wp_schedule_update_user_counts(),""twice a
> day""
> "wp_site_health_scheduled_check,WP_Site_Health->wp_cron_scheduled_check(),""once
> weekly"" "wp_delete_temp_updater_backups,2023-08-16 16:33:02 6 Tage,
> wp_delete_all_temp_backups(),""once weekly""
> publish_future_post,[7],2040-09-03 03:02:56 17 Jahre,
> check_and_publish_future_post(),one-shot,0

Answer (score 1):

The line in question is:

```
$desc = html_entity_decode( $item->get_description(), ENT_QUOTES, get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
```

Which heavily implies that a widget in your site, one that's rarely used, has a null value for its description, or doesn't bother to define one.

You will need to search for such a widget. It may be that it does not call the parent constructor in its constructor to pass it along.

Answer (score 0):

No plugin and a fresh Twenty Twenty Two Theme is used...and still the warnings once a day....
I opened a ticket;
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/59052
...and got this answer:

> "Thanks for reporting this.
>
> In contrast to most reports of this kind (which are caused by
> plugins/themes doing it wrong), this does actually look like something
> which should be handled/fixed in WP Core in the wp_widget_rss_output()
> function.
>
> It appears that the RSS feed/URL is missing the description element
> and the code looping through the RSS feed items doesn't take that
> possibility into account. By the looks of it (based on a quick
> glance), it also doesn't correctly handle the possibility that other
> expected elements could be missing.
>
> While it is debatable whether that makes the RSS feed invalid (would
> need checking against the RSS specifications/RFC), I do think WP
> should handle this gracefully."